# File formats for streaming videos in HTML 5 in regular and mobile devices?

Tags: video-encoding, html5-video

I'm putting together a site that will include some instructional videos that will be 1 to 3 minutes long. The users will be accessing these through standard and mobile browsers. I'm particularly concerned with users of i-devices, such as iPhone/iPod Touch/iPad.

To deliver the videos, I'm will probably use videojs.com player - it seems like a pretty robust choice. Unfortunately, I don't know first thing about what file formats and standards to use for encoding files. H.264 Baseline profile seems to be a good choice, but I really need some direction on where to read up on what might be the best choice.

Please help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best resource I've found for this information is [Dive Into HTML 5](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html#what-works). They have a very concise breakdown of which formats will work with each of the browsers.

The long and short of it, however, is that h264 baseline is the way to go, especially if your HTML5 video player has Flash failover.

While HTML5 video is currently the standard in the mobile space, a back of the envelope calculation reveals that only about [40% of desktop browsers users can view it](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-200906-201007) as compared to [Flash's 99%+ market penetration](http://www.adobe.com/products/player_census/flashplayer/version_penetration.html). Moreover, you'd have to encode and store your videos twice (h264 and Theora) in order to reach all HTML5 video capable browsers.

However, by using h264 video and a Flash failover, you can cover all iDevices plus all browser that either don't support HTML5 video, or support HTML5 video for a format other than h264.

One word of warning: [iDevices only support the h264 baseline up to level 3.0](http://forum.handbrake.fr/viewtopic.php?p=21364), so make sure to stay within [these specs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC#Levels).

Hopefully that helps.